# local variable context_dict referenced before assignment

Tags: python, django

I am making a django app .According to me everything is in views.py but when i run the server it generates an error `local variable 'state' referenced before assignment`

I have made the context_dict variable in the above view but then too it is generating error.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import States,Colleges

def index(request):
    all_states = States.objects.all()
    context_dict = {'all_states':all_states}
    return render(request,'practise_app/index.html',context_dict)

def college(request,state_slug):

    try:
        state = States.objects.get(slug = state_slug)
        colleges = Colleges.objects.filter(state = state)
        context_dict = {'state':state,'colleges':colleges}

    except States.DoesNotExist:
        pass

    return render(request,'practise_app/colleges.html',context_dict)
```

TRACEBACK:

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/madhya-pradesh/

Django Version: 1.8
Python Version: 3.5.1
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'practise_app')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware')


Traceback:
File "C:\Users\sahib navlani\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in get_response
  132.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "D:\practise_project\practise_app\views.py" in college
  19.     return render(request,'practise_app/colleges.html',context_dict)

Exception Type: UnboundLocalError at /madhya-pradesh/
Exception Value: local variable 'context_dict' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Just means your `try` block threw an exception. You could just use `context_dict = {}` in you `except block.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's pretty obvious, your code went to the `except` block, but `context_dict` is only defined in `try` block, so when you use it in your `render` function, it's not defined. The quickest fix is to define `context_dict` as empty dict at the beginning of the function so that it's always there when you return it.